# Mentoring students - Computer Science

Tags: research-process, mentoring

I am interested in mentoring students (undergrad / MSc) in areas of Artificial Intelligence and Software Engineering.

Unfortunately, the university I graduated from/ currently work at do not offer such mentoring programs; however, this is a valuable experience that I wish to gain.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what kind of mentoring you have in mind?  Research supervision, career advice, general academic support, etc?  Also, what's your current status: professor, postdoc, grad student, industry professional, ?

Comment: And: Are you looking for this as experience to prepare you for something in particular, or just because you think it'll be generally rewarding?

Comment: I am a postdoc. I am interested to mentor  research projects. This will help me deepen my knowledge on one hand, and on the other, could be useful for my job search.

Comment: As a postdoc you should have plenty of chance to supervise MSc and PhD students. Ask your boss.

Answer (score 3):

To answer with something fully external to your university:

#### [Google Summer of Code](https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/)

Google Summer of Code is a program that is about getting university students (undergrad or postgrad) contributing to open source.

Some open source project can be very technical/scientific.
I've mentored this year and last for JuliaLang/NumFocus.
Since Julia is a language primarily aimed at researchers, many of our projects are very technical.
The project I co-mentored last year was literally to implement and improve an algorithm from a paper.*

JuliaLang runs a bunch of AI projects each year.
I am sure the R and Python communities do too.

*<sub>[Lagaris, Isaac E., Aristidis Likas, and Dimitrios I. Fotiadis. "Artificial neural networks for solving ordinary and partial differential equations." IEEE Transactions on Neural Networks 9, no. 5 (1998): 987-1000.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/9705023.pdf)</sub>